# Show Variable from List in ListView

Tags: android, list, listview, arraylist

I have a List of Locations

```
ArrayList<Location> locationList;
```

Each Location contains informations like name, adress, description ...
I only want to show the Name in each Row so you can select the Location you want to receive more Information in a new Intent.

I managed to show strings in a ListView by using this code:

```
    locationNames= new String[]{"I","am", "a", "ListView"};

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem,
            locationNames));
    ListView locationListview;
    locationListview = getListView();
    locationListview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

This works so far, but I can't show contents of a List in this listView, nor can I ask for more informations about the clicked row.

I thought about reading the first element of the list to save them in a string array.
This will cause problems when you want to click them to get more information.

What is the best way to do this?

Sincerly,
Wolfen

Comment: How are you getting (or building) `locationList`? There are built-in adapters (like the SimpleCursorAdapter for Cursors) that make quick work of this or you can write a custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are asking for.

Put the name of the locations in a String array like so:

```
String names[] = new String[locationList.size()];

int i=0;
for( Location loc:locationList )
{
    names[i] = loc.name;
    i++;
}
```

Then use this array `names` instead of `locationNames` in your adapter:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem, names));
```

Finally set a listener to your list in order to get the item click event:

```
    locationListview.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            // Read your location information using the position parameter
            Location l = locationList.get( position );

            // Show the rest of the location info ...

        }               
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Location[] locationArray = new Location[locationList.size()];
locationList.toArray(locationArray); 
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Location>(this, R.layout.singleitem,
locationArray));
```

and override Location's **toString()** method to return the name of the location. If you didn't create the Location class yourself, you'll need to create a subclass to override the toString() method.

Comment: If you create a new `ArrayAdapter<Location>` and pass it an array as its 3rd parameter, the array type must be `Location`. You are passing it `locationArray` which you have declared as `String[]`. Also, to override the `toString()` method of `Location`, you need to create a class which extends `Location` (which you haven't explained).